# App Service Certificate - Can't verify domain

Tags: azure, ssl

I am trying to set up a SSL certificate my root domain and all sub domains.

The key vault configuration is done but i am unable to verify domain; so far i did put a html file which has the same name with Domain Verification Token also created a TXT record with the same value on root domain.

The first verification option also seems working not  in a correct way, it's not listing my custom domain in the list even though it's added already. Also all the sub domains have standart or premium pricing options.

Could any body help me with that issue? Thank you.

Comment: I've had some problems with this lately. Any chance this domain is associated with anything else in Azure whether it's an Azure Subscription or something else (especially Office 365)? They made some changes in October that causes some unfortunate collisions between various Azure-hosted services.

Comment: Nope. There were just a DNS Zone related to that domain and deleted it a while ago. Nothing like 365 or other subscription.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have just done a similar setup if you need any assistance